# Visual Studio 2008 external tool command to open 64-bit version of RegEdit

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, regedit

I was trying to add an external tool command to `VS2008` tools menu to open `regedit` in 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

I can open a 32-bit version of RegEdit as such:

[image]

But since VS process itself is a 32-bit process what is the command to open a 64-bit version of `regedit`?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write your own small app to do it for you, or simply use [this one](http://www.dennisbabkin.com/php/downloads/OpenRegedit.zip). That one can also run multiple instances of `regedit` which is nice. I have it in the `Visual Studio` external tools menu as such:

```
path-to-it\OpenRegedit.exe
```

command line for 64-bit:

```
-x64
```

or for 32-bit:

```
-x86
```